# Database for AR app for storing 3D models

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, arcore

I was learning about Augmented Reality and developing an AR app using Google's AR-Core. Its working fine with single models, but I was thinking if I could upload different 3D models in database and app would fetch models from database and show to the screen.

Edit:
I want to load models run-time from database.
Is there another way apart from GLTF2, like OBJ or FBX to load during run-time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two examples of ways you work with multiple models in your app, which is what I think is what your goal is, are:

- Include multiple Renderables in the app at build time
- Add the ability to load and build models at run time

An example of the first is shown below. This loads and builds all the renderables in the 'raw' folder of the app, in the Main ACtivity's onCreate function (this example is Kotlin below). This example uses a class 'MetaRenderable' which is simply a class with properties to store the renderable name and the renderable itself. It searches for renderables by looking for a known text string in the name in the raw folder but you could simply each for all '.sfb' files:

```js
  override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        //Check that AR is supported on this device
        if (!checkIsSupportedDeviceOrFinish(this)) {
            return
        }

        //Create the set of renderables
        val rawFields: Array<Field> = R.raw::class.java.fields
        for (i in 0 .. rawFields.count() - 1) {
            val resID = rawFields[i].getInt(rawFields[i])
            val value = TypedValue()
            resources.getValue(resID, value, true)
            val rawFileName = value.string.toString()
            if (rawFileName.contains("com_yourpackagename_")) {
                //This is a renderable so build it and add it to the list
                Log.d(TAG,"rawFileName: " + rawFileName)
                ModelRenderable.builder()
                    .setSource(this, resID)
                    .build()
                    .thenAccept{
                        val newMetaRenderable:MetaRenderable = MetaRenderable()
                        newMetaRenderable.name = rawFields[i].name.substringAfter("com_yourpackagename_renderable_")
                        newMetaRenderable.renderable = it
                        listOfMetaRenderables.add(newMetaRenderable)
                        //Set the default renderable
                        if(rawFileName.contains("your_defaul_trenderable_name")) {
                            selectedRenderable = it
                        }
                    }
                    .exceptionally {
                        Log.d(TAG, "Could not build Renderable id: " + resID)
                        Toast.makeText(this@MainActivity, "Could not build one of the renderables", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                        return@exceptionally null
                    }
            }
        }
```

For the second example approach, loading at run time, you can use the RenderableSource.Builder object. This will allow you build a renderable at runtime for a give URL, although it is restricted to 'GLTF2' files at this time, AFAIK.

> RenderableSource.Builder
>   setSource(Context context, Uri modelUri, RenderableSource.SourceType sourceType)
>   Sets the Uri of the asset to be imported.

Documentation is here:

- https://developers.google.com/sceneform/reference/com/google/ar/sceneform/assets/RenderableSource.Builder

And there is an example project which browses, downloads and builds models from Google's Poly website here:

- https://github.com/googlesamples/sceneform-poly-browser